# Codeigniter doesn't get ID and update database not work

Tags: database, codeigniter

I've learn a simple updating scripts using Codeigniter but I have a problem, the data won't updated because its not get the id. But when I tried running the query using SQL syntax in mysql it worked and updated the data.

Here's my table (Member):

```
id | Name | Job | Age
_____________________
1  |Joe   |None | 30
2  |Mike  |None | 23
3  |Alice |None | 21
```

**and here's my controller scripts to get the data by id:**

```
public function update_now($id)
  {

    $name = $this->input->post('name');
    $job  = $this->input->post('job');
    $age  = $this->input->post('age');

    $query = $this->m_update->update_data($name, $job, $age);
    if ($query > 0) {
        }
    redirect('data_detail');
```

**Here's my model scripts:**

```
function update_data($name, $job, $age)
{
  $query=$this->db->query("update member SET name='$name', job='$job', age='$age' where id='$id'");
 }
```

When I tried to tested the scripts, changed `where id=1` it worked, but it doesn't worked when I've changed to `$id` it doesn't get the data ID. Did I missed something?
Thank you for all solution and suggestions.

Comment: I'd suggest to read through: CI updating data: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#updating-data

Answer (score 1):

In your form you need to submit the data with the ID in the url like so:

```
<form method="post" action="<?= base_url("route/$id") ?>">
    ....
</form>
```

Then you must send that id into your model with something like this:

```
$data = array(
    'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
    'job' => $this->input->post('job'),
    'age' => $this->input->post('age')
);

$query = $this->m_update->update_data($id, $data);

if ($query) {
     redirect('data_detail');
}
```

At this point your model should be changed to:

```
function update_data($id, $data) {
  return $this->db->where('id', $id)->update("member", $data);
}
```

For more information you should check the user guide here:

[Codeigniter 3 - Updating data using the query builder](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#updating-data)

Answer (score 0):

You have not passed the $id to the function `update_data` in model.

Change the code as follows:

**controller**:

```
public function update_now($id)
{
$name = $this->input->post('name');
$job  = $this->input->post('job');
$age  = $this->input->post('age');

$query = $this->m_update->update_data($name, $job, $age, $id);
if ($query > 0) {
    }
redirect('data_detail');
}
```

**model**:

```
function update_data($name, $job, $age, $id)
{
  $query=$this->db->query("update member SET name='$name', job='$job', age='$age' where id='$id'");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Your form must have this format:

```
<form method="post" action="<?= base_url("route/$id") ?>">
    ....
</form>
```

It will work then.

Comment: This my form format `<form method="post" class="form-horizontal form-label-left" action="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/masterdata/update_now' ?>">`

Comment: Where is the id you are passing to _update_now_ method to update data against?

Comment: from the controller (edit function), first I get the id from my view page `.../edit/1` then it showed the data based on the ID, then I clicked the submit button after finished editing and it will run the controller `update_now`.

Comment: Pass the id value get from `.../edit/1` to the edit form view and echo in the form action as third parameter. So you will be able to get that id when you submit the form.